# Answering non-Homebrew specific questions with Homebrew specific solutions

Tags: discussion, allowed-answers

I have recently found a lot of old console related questions that are either unanswered or the answer is just a variation of "this is not possible", but I feel that it will probably be a good idea to update them by mentioning that is possible via Homebrew. even if the person asking the question didn't mentioned Homebrew explicitly. This will probably help other users that find the question in the future.

Would this be the correct thing to do?

For example, [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/340324/ps-vita-black-screenshots) asks about the screenshots on some games being shown as black pictures, but there is a [Homebrew plugin](https://github.com/xyzz/pngshot) that fixes this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encourage you to add your expertise to any question where a potential solution exists, whether that solution is through homebrew or otherwise.

While those that want an "official" answer may balk at the notion, answers with alternative solutions are definitely welcome, especially moreso in the case of systems where official support has dried up.

Comment: "systems where official support has dried up" is mainly why I asked this question. There have been a lot of improvements done by the Homebrew community for the PS3, PSP and PS Vita even after they were discontinued (the manufacturing of those consoles, they can still connect to PSN).